# C++ SQL Server connection on 64 bit system

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

Here is my code for connect local SQL Server with Visual Studio 2019.

```
SQLHANDLE sqlConnHandle = nullptr;
SQLHANDLE sqlStmtHandle = nullptr;
SQLHANDLE sqlEnvHandle = nullptr;
SQLRETURN error = 0;

if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlEnvHandle))
    std::cout << "SQLAllocHandle() sqlEnvHandle error" << std::endl;

if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlEnvHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER*)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0))
    std::cout << "SQLSetEnvAttr() sqlEnvHandle error" << std::endl;

if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlEnvHandle, &sqlConnHandle))
        std::cout << "SQLSetEnvAttr() sqlConnHandle error" << std::endl;

std::cout << "Connecting..." << std::endl;

error = SQLDriverConnect(
    sqlConnHandle,
    NULL,
    (SQLWCHAR*)L"Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=Yes;",
    SQL_NTS,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT
);
```

It works good on 32 bit system.
When I switch to 64 bit I have error during `SQLDriverConnect()`:

- SQL State: IM002
- Error code: 0

fetched with `SQLGetDiagRec()`;

I installed 64 bit version of ODBC driver from this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#download-for-windows
but nothing changed.

1. What is difference for connection on 32 and 64?
2. How I can debug what is problem?

Comment: Somewhere you load different libs. They must match 64 bit for Visual Studio 64 bit compile.

Comment: `Driver={SQL Server}` means you're not using the driver you downloaded.  Try with this sample app first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/cpp-code-example-app-connect-access-sql-db?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft  i resolwed problem with connection. Now i can not include sqlncli.h file provided by ODBC driver. What i need for include this file?

Answer (score 1):

After OBDC driver installation connection string is:

```
(SQLWCHAR*)L"Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
```

Names list of installed drivers you can find in: ODBC Data Cource Administrator -> System DSN -> Add...

Answer (score 0):

SQL State: IM002: possible reasons

> (DM) The driver listed in the data source specification in system information was not found or could not be connected to for some other reason.
>
> On 32-bit and 64-bit Windows, the default ODBC Administrator tool is
> in c:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe. However, on a 64-bit Windows
> machine, the default is the 64-bit version. If the 32-bit ODBC
> Administrator tool is needed on a 64-bit Windows system, run the one
> found here: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

Check the exact driver name in the ODBC Administrator tool. Press Windows key + R and then:

- `C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe` on 32-bit systems
- `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` on 64-bit systems

[image: ODBC Data Source Administrator]

[What is difference for connection on 32 and 64?](https://techterms.com/help/difference_between_32-bit_and_64-bit_systems#:%7E:text=A%2032%2Dbit%20processor%20includes,but%20is%204%2C294%2C967%2C296%20times%20larger.)

Comment: can you carefuly read your message? i can not understand: If the 32-bit ODBC Administrator tool is needed on a 64-bit Windows system, run the one found here: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe   Then - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe on 64-bit systems